# Does Firefox in VM have a common enough fingerprint so I don't need tor browser?

Tags: firefox, fingerprinting, virtual-machine

I want to know about what a web browser's fingerprint like in a VM, if VM runs a common OS and have default system settings. Can VM be configured to not have any of host machine's fingerprint?

Here the VM software we discuss would better be FOSS, like Virtualbox or qemu.

This question can be on not just web browser, but also other kind of softwares.

(Here I just want to ask about fingerprint, ignoring IP addresses, web scripts and tracking cookies)

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with Tor but with browsers in general and would be better asked in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Tor.

Answer (score 1):

There are several online tools that allow you to test the fingerprint of Tor Browser and other browsers. For example, the Electronic Frontier Foundation's [panopticlick.eff.org](http://panopticlick.eff.org). Using these tools, it is straightforward to get a general idea of the uniqueness of your fingerprint with different browsers.

For example, using Panopticlick while running the default configuration of Tor Browser 9.0.2 for Linux, I get the result that the browser has **10.2 bits** of uniquely identifying information, and in the past 45 days, only one in **1176.04 browsers** using that service had the same fingerprint.

Performing the same experiment on a fresh install of Firefox 71.0 running in a VirtualBox Windows 10 VM, I get a Panoticlick result of **16.58 bits** of identifying information, and **one in 97636 browsers** had the same fingerprint.

While these tests may not check for every possible fingerprinting method, they at least suggest that the default Tor Browser configuration is much more anonymous than the default Firefox configuration running on a VM.